# Echo the 4 letters of a row in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following command which working fine

```
$sql = "SELECT Login,Email,Balance,`Group` FROM users where Email = '' ";
```

The output in the Group is like that when I do

```
echo " Group " . $row["Group"]. ;

real/something
demo/something

demo/something2
real/something3
```

How can I show only the four letters ?

Comment: "_How can I show only the four letters ?_" What four letters exactly?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: It's clear that you're going to be with us for a while. You might like to read the help pages.

Comment: lets say real , demo. Also Strawberry I am not going to be with you a while. A like a lot stackoverflow and I am trying to start learn programming. I have arround 5-7 questions this month. I like a lot of that website because is realy helpful

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: Do you mean `echo " Group " . substr($row["Group"],4);` if you do it in PHP

Comment: Try using SUBSTRING(`Group`, 1, 4) in your sql.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, this question is a bit hard to read. It might be that English is not your first language ( is mine neither, I understand it can be hard sometimes)  and this is creating some mis-understanding in what you are actually asking.

But from what I deduct, what you are trying to do is that instead of

```
real/something
demo/something
```

you want the output to be

```
real
demo
```

This is easily achived with a few methods, the easiest is probably using [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php), this allows you to get parts of a string. In this case something like this is useful

```
$var = substr(0, 4, $row["Group"]);
```

But you should really take the above suggestion of an MCVE and a clear question structure into consideration. I am still not sure if I am correct in understanding your question.